# MySQL copy data inside single table, depending on column

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
post_id, meta_id,  meta_value
0000001, counter1, 00023
0000001, counter2, 00003
0000002, counter1, 00035
0000002, counter2, 00555
0000003, counter1, 00452
0000003, counter2, 00533
.
.
.
0007888, counter1, 04520
0007888, counter2, 00233
```

For each Post_ID, I want to change the values of rows with meta_id = counter2 to be the same as those with meta_id = counter1, like this:

```
post_id, meta_id,  meta_value
0000001, counter1, 00023
0000001, counter2, 00023
0000002, counter1, 00035
0000002, counter2, 00035
0000003, counter1, 00452
0000003, counter2, 00452
.
.
.
0007888, counter1, 04522
0007888, counter2, 04522
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What if there are more then two records per post_id.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5211/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`post_id` int, `meta_id` varchar(8), `meta_value` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`post_id`, `meta_id`, `meta_value`)
VALUES
    (0000001, 'counter1', 00023),
    (0000001, 'counter2', 00003),
    (0000002, 'counter1', 00035),
    (0000002, 'counter2', 00555),
    (0000003, 'counter1', 00452),
    (0000003, 'counter2', 00533)
;

update t
join t as tin
  on tin.post_id = t.post_id and
     tin.meta_id != t.meta_id
set t.meta_value = tin.meta_value
where t.meta_id = 'counter2';
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5211/1/0)**:

```
| post_id |  meta_id | meta_value |
|---------|----------|------------|
|       1 | counter1 |         23 |
|       1 | counter2 |         23 |
|       2 | counter1 |         35 |
|       2 | counter2 |         35 |
|       3 | counter1 |        452 |
|       3 | counter2 |        452 |
```